# password authentication failed for user "postgres" with docker-compose up on EC2

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

On EC2 linux server create by docker-machine, when I launch docker postgres:10.6 by **docker-compose up**, I have these loop errors :

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

I don't have these errors if I start container manually
=> docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword postgres:10.6

I don't have these errors in my local docker.

My docker-compose :

```yaml
db:
  container_name: postgres
  image: postgres:10.6
  restart: always
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPassword
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 20):

It might be because the volume (or bind mount directory) being already initialized after your first start. The postgres user, and database creation only happens on the first start (ie, /var/lib/postgresql/data must not already contain database files).
Try to run:

- `docker-compose rm -fv postgres` to delete any containers or volumes (in particular).
- `docker-compose up -d` to start your container.

Comment: Use `docker-compose rm -sfv postgres` instead, if you are not sure whether the container is running or not

Comment: I had to run `docker volume ls` to find the name of the volume, and then `docker volume rm <volume_name>`.  Then I could reinitialize the postgres volume

Comment: thanks a lot. It helps. In my case, when I create docker image at the first time I run with `sudo`.  I advise others also don't repeat my mistake

Comment: I had to make sure no app was still referencing the db with the old credentials..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that I have the answer to my question, it's not a bug I just have something that tries to connect permanently to postgres (through port 5432 which is open) ...

After search, I think it's an attempt at hacking because incoming connections never come from the same IP

```
connection received: host=45.120.120.149.81 port=47118
connection received: host=210.4.125.252 port=44774
connection received: host=82.223.55.254 port=36320
```

etc....

Comment: If you previously had PgAdmin setup with Postgres w/o a password, and then tried setting one via POSTGRES_PASSWORD, you will also see repeating login failures just like this.